# How to integrate Visual Studio Coded UI Tests with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I would be grateful if somebody could help me with the following situation: We have just started our first automated UI tests with CodedUITest module from Visual Studio 2012. We want to run these tests with Jenkins service which we currently use only to run our UI tests. 
I've read that I need the Jenkins MSTest plugin and I also have to install the Visual Studio 2012 Test Agent. What further steps and configuration I need to do?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would really like to see an answer on this one :/